# Enable-SPSessionStateService problem

Tags: session

I have enabled session state SQLSERVER mode in SharpePoint 2013 by running `Enable-SPSessionStateService` PowerShell commmand.

Now, when I open my custom webpart form, it throws below error, any idea?
[image]

Comment: Check This [Article](http://nikpatel.net/2012/02/12/enable-asp-net-session-state-on-sharepoint-2010-application/),It may help you

Comment: possible duplicate of [serialization error after session state enabled](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134537/serialization-error-after-session-state-enabled)