# serialization error after session state enabled

Tags: serialization

I am getting the follwoing error when i open visual webpart in a custom list form.I have enabled session state for the application. any idea?

```
SerializationException: Type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Fields.ImageFieldValue'
```

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue, and http://www.alexbruett.net/?p=255 is not accessible.